# Spring boot: Cannot resolve method 'builder' in 'Product'

Tags: java, spring, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have used @builder anotation of lombok in Product class. But when I use Product.builder(), it's not work.
Also, the getter and setter are cannot resolve. I have tried to downgrade some lombok versions, still not working.

This is my code in ProductService:

```
package dev.beyondnguyen.productservice.service;

import dev.beyondnguyen.productservice.dto.ProductRequest;
import dev.beyondnguyen.productservice.model.Product;
import dev.beyondnguyen.productservice.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    public void createProduct(ProductRequest productRequest) {
        Product product = Product.builder()
                .name(productRequest.getName())
                .description(productRequest.getDescription())
                .price(productRequest.getPrice())
                .build();

        productRepository.save(product);
        log.info("Product {} is saved", product.getId());
    }

}
```

And the code in Product class:

```
package dev.beyondnguyen.productservice.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Document(collection = "products")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

What is happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you share the dependency of lombok that you use ? just update your question

Answer (score 1):

It can be a problem in your, maven/gradle dependency that you import. Be sure, that project lombok dependency is imported as

Gradle:

```
compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: 'yourVersionOfLombok'

annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:yourVersionOfLombok'
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
<artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
<version>yourVersionOfLombok</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

```
               <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version yourVersionOfLombok</version>
                </path>                         
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Something like this.
Let me know if it help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IntelliJ IDEA, you need to install the Lombok plugin so it can understand the annotations of the Lombok library (Gradle/Maven) for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by downloading the Lombok plugin in my IntelliJ IDEA.

You can find more information on this on this article:

[solution-for-the-roblem-cannot-resolve-method-builder-in-spring-boot-with-lombok](https://www.trywithgeek.com/solution-for-the-roblem-cannot-resolve-method-builder-in-spring-boot-with-lombok/)